# Fractional integration and cointegration with R

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I am currently reading about fractional integration in the context of error correction models. Does anyone know of a package in R that has a function for Sowells maximum likelihood estimator of d?

Answer (score 2):

Well now we have `partialCI`: [An R package for the analysis of partially cointegrated time series](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/150014/1/880195347.pdf) by Matthew Clegg, Christopher Krauss and Jonas Rende

Answer (score 1):

The CRAN Task Views [page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.htmlhttps://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) for Time Series Analysis lists the [fracdiff package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fracdiff/index.html): Fractionally differenced ARIMA aka ARFIMA(p,d,q) models.

The package is described as follows:

Maximum likelihood estimation of the parameters of a fractionally differenced ARIMA(p,d,q) model (Haslett and Raftery, Appl.Statistics, 1989).

The documentation says that the package can perform the following methods:

- Geweke and Porter-Hudak (GPH) (1983)
- Reisen (1994) estimator
- Haslett and Raftery (1989)

Regarding Sowell's method from 1992, a number of academic articles ([example](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/papers2/Cheung-Diebold%20(1994).pdf)) report that they obtained the FORTRAN code from Fallaw Sowell. Probably, you could request the code and port it to R (if he or the licence approved of that)?!

I couldn't find an existing package with the implementation.